# Create and Bind DataGridViewColumn with query results. Add it to DataGridView

Tags: c#, binding, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I am desperately trying to add a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to my DataGridView programatically. Here is the Code I've got so far.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = _userBL.getUsersTable().DefaultView.ToTable(false, "Person_ID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Title", "Username");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ComboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
ComboBoxCell.Name = "State";
ComboBoxCell.ValueMember = "State";//ComboBoxCell.DisplayMember = "State";
ComboBoxCell.DisplayMember = "State"; 
ComboBoxCell.DataSource = _userBL.getUsersTable().DefaultView.ToTable(false, "State");
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(ComboBoxCell);
```

But i get no data in the comboboxcolumn, and since I added DataSource, I cannot add items (Active,Inactive) in it. Also, when I click it a small dropdown should appear, even for empty comboboxes, but it does not.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].OwningColumn;
            dt.Clear();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name from tblData", con);
            da.Fill(dt);
            combo.DataSource = dt;
            combo.DisplayMember = "name";
```

Comment: I'm getting unable to cast from DataGridViewTextBoxColumn to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn(your 1st line). Also, I do not understand why did you set the indexes the way you did.

Comment: My code also works, but because i had my datagridview,editmode = editprogramatically, i couldn't access dropdown list.